# Can I use Microsoft.Azure.Devices.RegistryManager to add/register an IoT Edge device?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-edge

Trying to search through Microsoft docs but I can't seem to find anything to suggest I can use `RegistryManager.AddDeviceAsync()` to add an IoT Edge (Preview) device to IoT Hub.

This [MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-create-deployment-with-cli-iot-extension) says you can pass the `--edge-enabled` option to the CLI command `az iot hub device-identity create -d edge001 -n blogDemoHub --edge-enabled` but how do I do this using the .NET SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(deviceId) { Capabilities = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared.DeviceCapabilities() { IotEdge = true } });
```

Comment: `Device does not contain a definition for 'Capabilities'`

and the namespace `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared` doesn't seem to contain the class `DeviceCapabilities`?

Comment: Azure IoT Edge is still in preview, so you have to use a nugget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices/1.16.0-preview-001